# Why is my app no longer getting beacon notices after being terminated due to memory pressure?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, ibeacon

My company has developed an iBeacon utility that will serve as either a beacon transmitter or a receiver (not both at the same time, purely for simplicity.)

It registers for both the bluetooth-central and bluetooth-peripheral background modes, and when it is in beacon receiver mode, it uses both startMonitoringForRegion and startRangingBeaconsInRegion.

When the app is in the background, and even if the device is locked, I get woken up in the background and am able to trigger local notifications or play sounds.

I have previously tested it and forced a low memory termination (simply by running my app from Xcode and then launching app after app until I see a message in the console that the app as been terminated dye to memory pressure.)

However, today I just tried it again, and despite waiting over an hour, if my app is terminated due to memory pressure while listening for new beacon regions, I am no longer getting re-launched when the beacon starts transmitting again. I made sure the beacon triggers a didEnterRegion when the app is in the foreground and when in the background.

I also tested it by launching the app from the springboard (not from Xcode) and launching dozens of heavyweight apps until I was pretty confident that my app had been terminated, and I don't get restarted with beacon notices in that case either.

I don't remember getting an iOS update since I first started testing it, but it seems like the system behavior has changed in the last couple of weeks. I don't have specific notes on when I tested it and the OS version I was using, but it sure seems like something that worked before is not longer working.

I have made various changes to the app to get it ready for distribution, but nothing that should affect this behavior. Does anybody else have any thoughts on why my app might stop getting re-launched when the system detects a beacon that I was actively monitoring when I was terminated due to memory pressure (not user-terminated.)

Comment: Is it possible that your application is unable to relaunch because memory pressure still exists?  What happens if you use the task manager to kill off all those apps you started up?

Comment: Apple version of a *slap on the wrist* >:)

Comment: @random, what does that mean? The memory pressure is from other running apps. Apple's WWDC videos on iBeacon explicitly state that the system is supposed to take over monitoring beacons on your app's behalf when you've been terminated due to memory pressure. I am doing everything right - at least to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: @davidgyoung, at your suggestion I tried terminating all the apps that I launched in order to get my app to be killed, and it doesn't make any difference. I'm trying the same test using Apple's AirLocate app now, and it seems it is ALSO failing to get beacon notifications after being terminated by memory pressure. (And quitting apps afterwords to then relieve the pressure.) I am suspecting that something changed on Apple's side. Can you re-test this with your company's app?

Comment: @DuncanC it was a bad joke :-/ I just got done testing on a few different devices with a few different variations of iBeacon implementation and seem to be having the same problem. I would file radar w/ Apple.

Comment: Funny, I have tried to reproduce this with Locate for iBeacon and cannot -- I never get a log message that the app is being terminated no matter how many other apps I launch on my 4S.  Instead, it keeps detecting new beacon regions and launching into the background.  What is iOS's algorithm for choosing apps to terminate in low memory situations?

Comment: 2 questions: 1) Out of curiosity, how were you certain that the app was terminated? 2) Was `didExitRegion` ever called?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tested on iOS 7.1? In iOS 7.0.x your app had to be at least running in the background in order to listen for beacons. Force quitting the app would terminate the connection. In 7.1, you should find that your issue is resolved. Even rebooting your device will not kill the connection in 7.1.

If you want to continue to support 7.0.x, you will have to find creative ways to keep users opening your app when it get killed in the background. You could poll a server at regular intervals and send a push notification when the connection fails, for example.

Comment: Is it possible that i can send UILocalNotifications when i enter a region of a beacon, even when the application terminated? My problem is that when the User killed the App and he is not using the phone that the Notifications will not be displayed.